# How to find where the sys.stderr is being printed in a Python module if it isn't showing up where expected?

Tags: python, stdout, stderr, sys

I'm working on a python module and some functions in said module print the stdout and stderr to custom log files.

```
# module_ex.py
import sys

def testfunc(errfile):
        sys.stdout = open(('stdout.file'),"w")
        sys.stderr = open((errfile),"w")

        print(str(2) + " " + "Hello")
        print(2 + " " + "Hello")
        return()

#script.py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import module_ex as mdx
mdx.testfunc("error.log")

#RUN
python script.py
```

In this example, sys redirects the stderr to error.log and it work as expected. However, in my module, sometimes error messages aren't showing up in their expected log files. I am wondering if this is due to a conflict with another library or a previous declaration of sys.stderr that is still valid and pointing my std.err into an unexpected direction.

Is there a way to verify the address where sys.stderr is pointing while inside a specific function in a module? For example, by printing the path to sys.stdout. In other words, how can I trace back where my std.err is being sent if I'm not seeing it?

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can inspect the `sys.stderr` object directly. If it's a normal file object, `sys.stderr.name` will be the file name.

For interactive debugging, `print(repr(sys.stderr))` should work pretty well.

As a side note, you should always save the original values of `sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr` before you modify them, and restore them when you're done. If you only need to redirect them within a single function, the `redirect_stdout()` and `redirect_stderr()` context managers in `contextlib` will handle all this for you.